# How to overload functions from the VBA standard library like IsEmpty()?

Tags: vba, excel

I want to make a local version of `IsEmpty()` in a class like this:

```
Public Dict As Dictionary

Public Function isEmpty(columnName As Variant) As Boolean
isEmpty = IsEmpty(Dict(columnName))
End Function
```

This is for information hiding, so that I can call

```
classInstance.isEmpty("someField")
```

instead of

```
isEmpty(classInstance.Dict("someField"))
```

and therefore not expose the class' internal data structure.

But the problem is that the version of `isEmpty()` that I've declared seems to be overriding any reference to the VBA library version of `IsEmpty()`, because it's generating an `Out of stack` error and crashing Excel.  I assume this is because the `isEmpty = IsEmpty(...)` call is causing infinite recursion.

Is there a way that I can explicitly reference the standard version of `IsEmpty()` that I would like to call here?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes. Explicitly reference the standard library.

```
VBA.IsEmpty()
```

**Bonus:**
`IsEmpty` actually belongs to the `Information` object. A *fully* explicit call looks like this.

```
bool = VBA.Information.IsEmpty(var)
```

[image: object browser]